# I am unable to COPY my CSV to postgres using psycopg2/copy_expert

Tags: postgresql, csv, copy, psycopg2

edit:
In **postgresql.conf**, the **log_statement** is set to:
**#log_statement = 'none'           # none, ddl, mod, all**

My objective is to COPY a .cvs file containing ~300k records to Postgres.

I am running the script below and nothing happens; no error or warning but still the csv is not uploaded.

Any thoughts?

```
import psycopg2

# Try to connect
try: 
  conn = psycopg2.connect(database="<db>", user="<user>", password="<pwd>", host="<host>", port="<port>")
  print("Database Connected....")
except:
  print("Unable to Connect....")


cur = conn.cursor()
try:    
  sqlstr = "COPY \"HISTORICALS\".\"HISTORICAL_DAILY_MASTER\" FROM STDIN DELIMITER ',' CSV"
  with open('/Users/kevin/Dropbox/Stonks/HISTORICALS/dump.csv') as f:
    cur.copy_expert(sqlstr, f)
  conn.commit()
  print("COPY pass")
except:
  print("Unable to COPY...")


# Close communication with the database
cur.close()
conn.close()
```

[This is what my .csv looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/as8qd.png)

Thanks!

Kevin

Comment: What does the Postgres log show when you do this? Add information as update to your question. Also try: `open('/Users/kevin/Dropbox/Stonks/HISTORICALS/dump.csv', 'r')`, *note* the 'r'.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver thanks, I added 'r' and same result. I do not have a log other than "Unable to COPY..."

Comment: "Unable to COPY..." is output of your Python code. What I am after is what is being shown in Postgres server log. In `postgresql.conf` what is `log_statement` set to? Add this information to your question not as a comment.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver, thanks, info was added to the question

Comment: Uncomment `log_statement` and set to `log_statement = mod` and then `reload` server to catch the change. Then you should see in the log what is happening when you do the `COPY`. Also in the `except`  `print` the exception: `except psycopg2.Error as e: print(e)`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to load in first time your df with pandas

```
import pandas as pd
import psycopg2
conn = psycopg2.connect(database="<db>", user="<user>", password="<pwd>", host="<host>", port="<port>")
cur = conn.cursor()
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
cur.copy_from(df, schema , null='', sep=',/;', columns=(df.columns))
```

For the part columns=(df.columns) I forgot if they want turple or list but should work with a conversion and you should read this
[Pandas dataframe to PostgreSQL table using psycopg2 without SQLAlchemy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54519912/pandas-dataframe-to-postgresql-table-using-psycopg2-without-sqlalchemy) who could help you